# Maintaining server session with session cookie Android app

Tags: php, android, session, cookies

I'm having a problem with my session check.

The first time I log in, I call the php login script in which I call `session_start()`, check with the DB if username and password are correct and in this case store $_SESSION["username"] and $_SESSION["id"] variables and retrieve $id variable that is `session_id()`;

Then I'm on the homepage of my app (that I want to protect if no session is opened), so in `onRestart` method of this home activity I call the `checkLogin()` function that runs the CheckLogin php script in which I call `session_start()`, `$id=session_id()` and check `if(isset($_SESSION["username"])` and `isset($_SESSION["id"])` and `$_SESSION["id"]==$id)`. In this case I retrieve echo 'logged' else 'error'

I saw that in my php.ini (using mysite/phpinfo.php) session.gc_maxlifetime is set to 1440 seconds but my CheckLogin script says that I'm still connected even if 8 hours passed. When I first login I save the `session_id()` in my sharedPreferences and then I pass this id in the checklogin request as Cookie parameter in this way

```
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setReadTimeout(15000);
        conn.setConnectTimeout(15000);
        conn.setUseCaches(true);
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setDoInput(true);
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        conn.setRequestProperty("Cookie","PHPSESSID="+id);
```

Please can anyone explain me why $_SESSION variables are still there 8 hours of inactivity later even if in php.ini maxlifetime is set to 1440?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Are you using JBoss?  If so, this might be a known bug http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35271668/cannot-set-timeout-on-resteasy-client-on-jboss

Comment: @Enwired no, and i don't even know what it is